# adding margin to DataRows of DataTable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I want to add some space between DataRows of DataTable to have some box shadow in there.
this the design that I should create:
[image: design]

[edit] code added
this is how  i have created the table.

this is what ive achive. i have  changed to DataTable source code to have some shadow but the get mixed because there is no margin
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:DigiHaseb/uiKit.dart' as K;

class Table extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  /// table headers as [List of Strings]
  final List<String> headers;

  /// the data that will be show in table
  final List<Object> data;

  /// model of data entered to the table
  final Object dataModel;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final Color? rowColor;
  final Color? seperatedRowColor;
  final Color? headerLabelColor;
  final Color? rowLabelColor;
  final Color? selectedColor;
  final Color? sepereatedSelectedColor;

  /// if this property is true it will seperete table rows with two colors
  final bool seperatedRows;

  /// to restrict the each table column width.
  /// [String] property of [Map] must be the same as [model's properties]
  final Map<String, double>? restrictedCells;

  /// this fuction executes on tabel row select event.
  /// it returns [null] or a [model instance].
  /// if it returns [null] it means user has unSelected the selected row.
  final Function(dynamic row)? onSelect;

  const Table({
    required this.headers,
    required this.data,
    required this.dataModel,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
    this.rowColor = const Color(0xFFECEFF1),
    this.seperatedRowColor = const Color(0xFFE8EAF6),
    this.headerLabelColor = Colors.black54,
    this.rowLabelColor = Colors.black,
    this.selectedColor = const Color(0xFFB0BEC5),
    this.sepereatedSelectedColor = const Color(0xFF9FA8DA),
    this.seperatedRows = false,
    this.restrictedCells,
    this.onSelect,
  });

  @override
  _TableState createState() => _TableState();
}

class _TableState extends State<Table> {
  //
  List<bool> selected = [];

  //Note: generates table headers with headet property
  List<K.DataColumn> _buildHeaders(List<String> headers) {
    return headers
        .map(
          (text) => K.DataColumn(
            label: Expanded(
              child: K.Text(text, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  //Note: generating table's content with data property
  List<K.DataRow> _buildRows() {
    return widget.data.map(
      (row) {
        final rowIndex = widget.data.indexWhere((element) => element == row);
        return K.DataRow(
          selected: selected[rowIndex],
          onSelectChanged: (value) => handleSelected(rowIndex, value!),
          color: getRowColors(rowIndex),
          cells: _buildCells(row),
        );
      },
    ).toList();
  }

  void handleSelected(int index, bool value) {
    setState(() {
      if (selected.contains(true)) {
        final selectedIndex = selected.indexWhere((element) => element == true);
        selected[selectedIndex] = false;
      }
      selected[index] = value;
      //Note: if table has onSelect property , sends back eighter null or row instance based on if user deselects the selected row or selects a row
      if (widget.onSelect != null)
        widget.onSelect!(selected[index] == true ? widget.data[index] : null);
    });
  }

  //Note: handling the row color based on its state and if it has seperadetRows or not
  MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? getRowColors(int index) {
    return MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected))
          return widget.seperatedRows
              ? ((index % 2 == 0)
                  ? widget.selectedColor
                  : widget.sepereatedSelectedColor)
              : widget.selectedColor;
        return widget.seperatedRows
            ? ((index % 2 == 0) ? widget.rowColor : widget.seperatedRowColor)
            : widget.rowColor;
      },
    );
  }

//Note: checks the data's model type and base on that creates the row cells
//Note: to support mutliple data types we should add the below functionally of them to the function
  List<K.DataCell> _buildCells(Object row) {
    List<K.DataCell> list = [];

    if (widget.dataModel == DataRowModel) {
      list = DataRowModel.generateTableDataCells(
        row as DataRowModel,
        list,
        widget.restrictedCells,
        widget.rowLabelColor!,
      );
    }
    return list;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Note: generating lselected list based on data length
    selected = List<bool>.generate(widget.data.length, (index) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      color: widget.backgroundColor,
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: K.DataTable(
          showCheckboxColumn: false,
          backgroundColor: widget.backgroundColor!,
          columns: _buildHeaders(widget.headers),
          rows: _buildRows(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataRowModel {
  final String number;
  final String code;
  final String text;

  DataRowModel({required this.number, required this.code, required this.text});

  // static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(DataRowModel dataRowModel) {
  //   return {
  //     'number': dataRowModel.number,
  //     'code': dataRowModel.code,
  //     'text': dataRowModel.text,
  //   };
  // }

  //Note: generates the cells related to _buildCells function in table widget
  // Note: every model that will be used in order to create a table must have this function
  static List<K.DataCell> generateTableDataCells(
    DataRowModel row,
    List<K.DataCell> list,
    Map<String, double>? restrictedCells,
    Color rowLabelColor,
  ) {
    //
    Widget cellWidget(String value) {
      return Center(
        child: K.Text(value),
      );
    }

    var cell;

    final map = {
      'number': row.number,
      'code': row.code,
      'text': row.text,
    };
    map.forEach(
      (key, value) {
        restrictedCells != null
            ? restrictedCells.forEach(
                (rkey, rvalue) {
                  key == rkey
                      ? cell = Container(
                          width: rvalue,
                          child: cellWidget(value),
                        )
                      : cell = cellWidget(value);
                },
              )
            : cell = cellWidget(value);
        list.add(K.DataCell(cell));
      },
    );
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you provide code you tried out?

Comment: @Mol0ko Hi. OK, I'm using DataTable widget.

Comment: @Mol0ko I added the source code

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not change this, they are hard coded.
To Solve your problem, copy the source code of `datatable` and make a `customDatatable`, with your configuration (like height, shadows etc).

Here is the [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart#L615)

By the way, why using datatable? your interface looks quite simple, you can do the same thing with Container,row,column easily!

Comment: @xalid_rocks I have changed the datatable code but i cant find a place to add margin to each row